# Push file into Android device

Tags: android, download, push

Is it possible to programatically push a file into the SD card of an Android device over the network? How can this be done?

Comment: This question, having nothing to do with programming, is better asked on ForceClose.com.

Comment: Is it really necessary to say programatically on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into Android to do this, strictly speaking.

You are welcome to use [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/), at least when it is ready for production use, and write a C2DM app pair (on-device, on-server) to arrange to deliver a file. I think there are other third-party push solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox or UbuntuOne can do that :D